# Memory Management/Overview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I would Like to Know if there's a way to see what is in the Memory wile Debugging.
eg. see what data-tables are still active ,Where most of the memory is allocated to ect...

I know about the "Watch" Feature in VS2013 But its not really what I'm looking for,I want to know what objects i did not dispose of correctly.And to go trough it manually is HARD!Something like a memory overview.I have tried Process explorer too but it only shows how mush the process is using at the moment in total,its good to check for a Memory leak however.

If Something like this exists is there a tutorial you can point me to?

Comment: You need a (managed memory) "profiler", Visual Studio's or standalone. Other than that, this question is pretty broad and likely to be closed.

Comment: You're looking for a memory profiler. Visual studio has one, or Ants profiler. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTS Memory Profiler will allow you analyze which objects are in memory when you expect them not to. As well as let you investigate why that is.

I'm sure there are other, similar tools.